# Click event on page load on a Select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select tag with 4 options. I want to get a particular option clicked when the page loads and a method should called because of click event. Here what I have tried so far:

#### HTML

```
<select>
  <option >Select an option...</option>
  <option >Option 1</option>
  <option >Option 2</option>
  <option >Option 3</option>
  <option id="lop"  onclick="myFunction()">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

#### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#lop").trigger("click");
    
  function myFunction(){
    alert("hi");
  }
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9o6ra3x/475/)

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

     var opt = $("#a").val();
      if (opt == 4) {
       myFunction();
      }
    
   function myFunction(){
   alert("hi");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=''>Select an option...</option>
  <option value=1>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2 >Option 2</option>
  <option value=3>Option 3</option>
  <option id="a" value=4>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, you should trigger a change event on select to trigger after the page load,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#lop").trigger("click");
  $('select').on('change', function(){
    var val= $(this).val();
    if(val == 4) myFunction();
  })
});

function myFunction(){
  alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=''>Select an option...</option>
  <option value=1>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2 >Option 2</option>
  <option value=3>Option 3</option>
  <option id="lop" onclick="myFunction()" value=4>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `on change` like below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert(this.value);

  $('.selectList').on('change', function(){
    alert(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectList">
  <option value=''>Select an option...</option>
  <option value=1>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2 >Option 2</option>
  <option value=3>Option 3</option>
  <option id="lop"  onclick="myFunction()" value=4>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change your Js with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function myFunction(){
 alert("hi");
 }

 $("#myselect").change(function() {
    var opt = $(this).val();
  if(opt == '4'){
    myFunction();
    }
});
 var opt1 = $("#myselect").val("4");
 if(opt1){
  myFunction();
 }
});
```

And remove onclick function from your option

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value=''>Select an option...</option>
  <option value=1>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2 >Option 2</option>
  <option value=3>Option 3</option>
  <option id="lop"  value=4>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way do this:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
   $('select').val('3').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value=''>Select an option...</option>
  <option value=1>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2 >Option 2</option>
  <option value=3>Option 3</option>
  <option id="lop"  onclick="myFunction()" value=4>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simply You can set the value of Select option dynamically like this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectInp").val(4);

});
```

**With HTML Provide an Id to your Select**

```
<select id="selectInp">
<option value=''>Select an option...</option>
 <option value=1>Option 1</option>
 <option value=2 >Option 2</option>
 <option value=3>Option 3</option>
 <option id="lop"  onclick="myFunction()" value=4>Option 4</option>
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j9o6ra3x/514/

**OR If you want to work as your Solution**
Simply,

```
$("#lop").trigger("click"); // Instead of
$("#lop").prop('select',true); // Put this on ready
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#mySelect").click(function(){
     var opt = $("#mySelect option:selected").val();
      if (opt == 4) {
       myFunction();
      }
    });
    
   function myFunction(){
   alert("hi");
   }
});
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value=''>Select an option...</option>
  <option value=1>Option 1</option>
  <option value=2 >Option 2</option>
  <option value=3>Option 3</option>
  <option value=4>Option 4</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j9o6ra3x/491/

Comment: snippet itself is not working, what type of answer is this ?

Comment: @saurabh kumar: Why need combinate this with select? Do simple with `$(document).ready(function(){ alert("hi"); }`; @Akhil Aravind jsFiddle link is posted. Snippet was easier typing...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` event to achieve the functionality you desire.

**using .change()**

```
$('#lop').change(function(){
        //your function
})
```

**using .bind()**

```
$('#lop').bind('change',function(){
 //your function
});
```

Then you can trigger change on page load:

```
$(function () {
   $("select#myselect").change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id='selectInp' size='<?php echo $prod_count;?>' onclick='window.loadStates()' class='form-control' name='categ'><li><option id='toate' value='999'>Toate produsele</option>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#selectInp").val(999);
      $("#toate").trigger("click");


});
```

Comment: Consider of adding explanations to your code and declare what parts you added or modified.

Comment: Try to adapt after this. I did it and it works for me...first you have to focus on the option you want to select then trigger a click event on it.

Answer (score 0):

at first, you should set an onload event for the body as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(select => {
    select.onload();
  });
}
```

the above code triggers the onload event for all select tags when the page is loaded.

now you should set the onload event for the select tag as like this:

```
<select onload="document.getElementById('#optionTagId').selected = true">
```